# Jupyter pyspark : no module named pyspark

Tags: python, ipython, pyspark, jupyter, apache-toree

Google is literally littered with solutions to this problem, but unfortunately even after trying out all the possibilities, am unable to get it working, so please bear with me and see if something strikes you.

OS: MAC

Spark : 1.6.3 (2.10)

Jupyter Notebook : 4.4.0

Python : 2.7

Scala : 2.12.1

I was able to successfully install and run Jupyter notebook. Next, i tried configuring it to work with Spark, for which i installed spark interpreter using Apache Toree. Now when i try running any RDD operation in notebook, following error is thrown

```
Error from python worker:
  /usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark
PYTHONPATH was:
  /private/tmp/hadoop-xxxx/nm-local-dir/usercache/xxxx/filecache/33/spark-assembly-1.6.3-hadoop2.2.0.jar
```

Things already tried:
1. Set PYTHONPATH in .bash_profile
2. Am able to import 'pyspark' in python-cli on local
3. Have tried updating interpreter kernel.json to following

```
{
  "language": "python",
  "display_name": "Apache Toree - PySpark",
  "env": {
    "__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__": "",
    "SPARK_HOME": "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/utils/spark",
    "__TOREE_OPTS__": "",
    "DEFAULT_INTERPRETER": "PySpark",
    "PYTHONPATH": "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/utils/spark/python:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/utils/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/utils/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/utils/spark/bin",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
    "PYTHON_EXEC": "python"
  },
  "argv": [
    "/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_pyspark/bin/run.sh",
    "--profile",
    "{connection_file}"
  ]
}
```

4. Have even updated interpreter run.sh to explicitly load py4j-0.9-src.zip and pyspark.zip files. When the opening the PySpark notebook, and creating of SparkContext, I can see the spark-assembly, py4j and pyspark packages being uploaded from local, but still when an action is invoked, somehow pyspark is not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use findspark lib to bypass all environment setting up process. Here is the link for more information.
https://github.com/minrk/findspark

Use it as below.

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/path_to_spark/spark-x.x.x-bin-hadoopx.x')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following command in Windows  to link pyspark on jupyter.

On *nix, use `export` instead of `set`

Type below code in CMD/Command Prompt

```
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
pyspark
```

Comment: This isn't using Jupyter, only ipython

Comment: When you execute this commands, it will open jupyter notebook in browser.
 As far as my understanding jupyter notebook is using ipython in background. If I am wrong then please correct me because i have already used this command

Comment: In my experience, (at least the first and third line here)  will stay in the terminal and give you an ipython prompt for Pyspark

Comment: Yes you are right, actually second line where i have mentioned notebook that leads to jupyter notebook on browser.

Comment: Got it... Anyways, the Apache Toree install sets this up as well

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to add:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = 'pyspark-shell'
```

After that, you can work with Pyspark normally.

Answer (score 0):

using:

- ubuntu 16.04 lts
- spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
- anaconda Anaconda3 4.4.0   (python3)

added the following to .bashrc (**adjust your SPARK_HOME path accordingly**):

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/gps/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

then in a terminal window run (**adjust path accordingly**):

```
$ /home/gps/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark
```

**this will start Jupyter Notebook with pyspark enabled**

Comment: Setting `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `ipython` or `jupyter` is a really *bad* practice, which can create serious problems downstream (e.g. [when trying `spark-submit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772280/spark-submit-cant-locate-local-file/46773025#46773025)).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a virtualenv and install pyspark
2. Then setup kernal

   ```
    python -m ipykernel install --user --name your_venv_name --display-name "display_name_in_kernal_list"
   ```
3. start notebook
4. Change kernel using dropdown

   ```
       Kernel >> Change Kernel >> list of kernels
   ```

Answer (score 0):

We create a file startjupyter.sh in the path where we have jupyter and keep all environment setting in this file say as stated above

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/gps/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

give a path for error and log file also in it.
you can also give the port number where you want to execute the notebook.
Save the file and execute ./startjupyter.sh
Check the Jupyter.err file it will give the token to access the Jupyter notebook online through url.