# Spark-submit can't locate local file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I've written a very simple python script for testing my spark streaming idea, and plan to run it on my local machine to mess around a little bit. Here is the command line:

```python
spark-submit spark_streaming.py localhost 9999
```

But the terminal threw me an error:

```python
Error executing Jupyter command '<the/spark_streaming.py/file/path>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have no idea why this would happen, and I'm sure the .py file does exist.

EDIT: there's no issue running it with `python` instead of `spark-submit`

And also, the lines added in the .bashrc file:

```python
export PATH="/usr/local/spark/bin:$PATH"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you want to `spark-submit` to YARN a Python script located at `/home/user/scripts/spark_streaming.py`, the correct syntax is as follows:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/user/scripts/spark_streaming.py
```

You can interchange the ordering of the various flags, but the script itself must be at the end; if your script accepts arguments, they should follow the script name (e.g. see [this example](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html#spark_yarn_sparkpi_example__section_e1c_qpz_35) for calculating pi with 10 decimal digits).

For executing locally with, say, 2 cores, you should use `--master local[2]` - use `--master local[*]` for all available local cores (no `deploy-mode` flag in both cases).

Check the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/submitting-applications.html) for more info (although admittedly they are rather poor in pyspark demonstrations).

PS The mention of `Jupyter`, as well the path shown in your error message are extremely puzzling...

**UPDATE**: Seems that `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter` messes up everything, funneling the execution through Jupyter (which is undesirable here, and it may explain the weird error message). Try modifying the environment variables in your `.bashrc` as follows:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark"  # do not include /bin
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=""
```

and `source .bashrc`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter how I configure those flags and args, the error remain the same. Speaking of `Jupyter`, I guess it could be due to some environment variables I set in .bashrc file? And by the way I don't have any problem running it with `python` as opposed to `spark-submit`, which is weird. lol

Comment: @JamesWong Jupyter should have nothing to do here. And where this `the/spark_streaming.py/file/path` comes from? Have you configured `SPARK_HOME`?

Comment: I didn't set SPARK_HOME anywhere explicitly as you can see in the updated post above. The spark_streaming.py file is simply the file sitting on the local disk.

Comment: Thank you very much. That config solved the error. But on the flip side, I can't launch jupyter notebook by `pyspark` anymore.

Comment: @JamesWong This way of using Jupyter with pyspark is obsolete & not recommended; kindly accept/upvote the answer if it resolved your issue, and possibly open another one with the new issue - my answer here could also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286021/how-to-use-jupyter-sparkr-and-custom-r-install/46346658#46346658

Comment: I use jupyter notebook most of the time. So my cofing is set to jupyter and notebook. Making it to python solved the problem. But I have to revert it back to jupyter to use noteook again.

Comment: I have added SPARK_HOME to env in linus but still getting the same error. Any advice/help anyone? Thanks!